# I'm trying to use track by on an ng-repeat but i get an error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use track by on an ng-repeat but i get the below error:

> angular-1.6.4.js:14525 Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received: 0
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/orderBy/notarray?p0=0
>       at angular-1.6.4.js:66
>       at angular-1.6.4.js:22268
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular-1.6.4.js:15358), :4:433)
>       at trackByIdExpFn (angular-1.6.4.js:31039)
>       at ngRepeatAction (angular-1.6.4.js:31096)
>       at $watchCollectionAction (angular-1.6.4.js:17861)
>       at Scope.$digest (angular-1.6.4.js:17999)
>       at Scope.$apply (angular-1.6.4.js:18269)
>       at done (angular-1.6.4.js:12387)
>       at completeRequest (angular-1.6.4.js:12613)

please see my angular code:

```
<tbody class="text-align:center list-body"  style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height:400px;"> 
    <tr ng-repeat="automatch in automatched track by $index | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse  | filter:search " >
        <td><input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" ng-model="automatch.ReasonID" ng-change="unMatchCheckAuto(automatch)" ></td>
        <td ng-show="trandateCol">{{automatch.TranDate}}</td>
        <td ng-show="valudateCol">{{automatch.ValueDate}}</td>
        <td ng-show="ageCol" ng-if="automatch.Age_In_Days <= slaDays" class="green-sla">{{automatch.Age_In_Days}}</td>
        <td ng-show="ageCol" ng-if="automatch.Age_In_Days > slaDays"  class="red-sla">{{automatch.Age_In_Days}}</td>
        <td ng-show="partranCol">{{automatch.Parttrantype}}</td>
        <td ng-show="amtCol" class="align-amount no-wrap">{{automatch.TranAmt | number:2}}</td>
        <td ng-show="tranpartCol" class="no-wrap">{{automatch.Reference}}</td>
        <td ng-show="tranpart2Col" class="no-wrap">{{automatch.Reference2}}</td>
        <td ng-show="debitCol" class="align-amount no-wrap">{{automatch.Debit | number:2}}</td>
        <td ng-show="creditCol" class="align-amount no-wrap">{{automatch.Credit | number:2}}</td>
        <td ng-show="tranidCol" class="no-wrap">{{automatch.TranID}}</td>
        <td ng-show="tranremarksCol" class="no-wrap">{{automatch.TranRemarks}}</td>
        <td ng-show="filenameCol" class="no-wrap">{{automatch.Filename}}</td>
        <td ng-show="datefromfilenameCol" class="no-wrap">{{automatch.DateIsManualMatch}}</td>
        <td ng-show="datefromfilenameCol" class="no-wrap">{{automatch.finalmatchid}}</td>
        <td ng-show="datefromfilenameCol" class="no-wrap">{{automatch.DateFromFilename}}</td>
        <td ng-show="idCol">{{automatch.ID}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: The right syntax to use order by is {{ array | orderBy : expression : reverse }} where expression can be a property from automatch for example orderBy:'id':true where id comes from automatch.id [read this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: The '`track by expn`' phrase should be at the end. Also since the `automatch` targets are objects and unique, it would be wiser to omit the `track by` expression and use the automatic tracking. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Tracking and Duplicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
ng-repeat="automatch in automatched | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:search track by $index "
```